# django: app not found when trying to import in urls

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 3.

I have the following project structure:

[image]

I am trying to import from my app "users" the "views" file as "users_view" in the main "urls.py" in django_devel_app

```
from users import views as users_views
```

the app is added in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', #Core authentication framework and its default models.
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', #Django content type system (allows permissions to be associated with models).
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
```

Nevertheless I am not able to do that in pycharm. It does not find the app "users and underlines "users" in urls.py saying "unresolved reference"?

If  i get do `python manage.py runserver` I get the following error message  `from . users import views as users_views ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_devel_app.users'`

Comment: Is the top django_devel_app in the screen shot the root folder of your project? Or is it wrapped in another folder?

Comment: many thanks for your help. The top folder shown is the root folder of this project, this is where manage.py is in

Comment: Does the project run if you do `python manage.py runserver`? Is it just an issue in pycharm or is there a python error?

Comment: If  i get do "python manage.py runserver" I get the following error message  "from . users import views as users_views ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_devel_app.users' "

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_devel_app.users

this error simply means "In your urls.py file, in your app directory, you need to specify the app name before above your urlpatterns dictionary. In your case your urls.py file will have the following,

```
app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [ path(),]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Djando has very often problems with editors or even IDEs, they don't
> translate links in the same way. So most of the time you see that
> there are errors in your code and when you change editor or IDE you
> don't see the same error.